# How to put back-end code for a label in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, xamarin

I am beginner to the C# and Visual Studio. I just wanted to ask how to put back-end code for a label.Just like when we press a double click on a button. It's back-end code just appears in .cs file, just like below

```
private void UIButton97_TouchUpInside(UIButton sender)
{
}
```

So can we do the same thing with a label.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Xamarin labels do not have touch events.  You can use gestures to workaround this.

Answer (score -1):

check event that available for label, and you can add some behavior in that event. for example i will use label in my current project :

1. Add Event Text Changed in the label

> ```
>    this.aboutLabel.TextChanged += new  System.EventHandler(this.aboutLabel_TextChanged);
> ```

2. Define method that handle event like below

> ```
>  private void aboutLabel_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
>      {
>         //do some bahaviour in here
>      }
> ```

The event above will be execute when text in label changed.

For simple way just right click --> properties in label element , click Events (In visual studio usually represent as thunderbolt image), double click empty field in beside event that you want to fire, see image below :

[image: event]

Comment: Please add a screenshot of the properties where the thunderbolt logo is located so that OP can see it visually.

Comment: sorry it seems the picture not appear in here, blocking by company proxy.